# Facebook Webhook Event block

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, vk, facebook-chatbot

I'm writing my facebook-chatbot and i need to register users who are turned off receiving messages from my bot. Is there any facebook webhook event, when user blocks bot messages? I need event like vk api `message_deny`.

Comment: You will notice it by the API response when trying to send a message to such a user. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/error-codes

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to explicitly tell that the user blocked your bot, but as @CBroe mentioned in this comment, you will get an error response from the API when the message fails to be delivered.